# How to force update in all components at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, momentjs

I'm trying to show relative time to now with momentjs, a few seconds ago, 5 minutes ago, an hour ago, etc... When the html renders, it shows the relative time, I mean, 'a few seconds' o 'an hour ago' depending on how old is the comment but it gets stuck in that state and never updates.

This is my code... Any suggestions?

```js
const components = new Set();
// Force update every component at the same time periodically
setInterval(() => {
  for (const comp of components) {
    comp.$forceUpdate();
  }
}, 60000);

Vue.component("FromNow", {
  template: '<span :title="title">{{ text }}</span>',
  props: ["date"],
  created() {
    components.add(this);
  },
  destroyed() {
    components.remove(this);
  },
  computed: {
    text() {
      return moment(this.date).fromNow();
    },
    title() {
      return moment(this.date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    },
  },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      comments: [
        {
          name: "Obedi1",
          id: 1,
          timestamp: 1587499864177,
          content: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae",
        },
        {
          name: "Jhonj2",
          id: 2,
          timestamp: 1587499872202,
          content: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae",
        },
        {
          name: "Janek3",
          id: 3,
          timestamp: 1587499898749,
          content: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae",
        },
        {
          name: "Markl4",
          id: 4,
          timestamp: 1587499904071,
          content: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index">
      <h3>{{ comment.name }}</h3>
      <from-now :date="comment.timestamp"></from-now>
      <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Relative time _to what_? Also, something to think about: `setInterval` does _not_ run "every X milliseconds", it runs at "at least" the interval length you indicate, so if that tab gets deprioritized, there is zero guarantee it'll fire even remotely near your 60s mark. Also note that "every minute" is rather far from "real time", so what are you actually trying to show? Because it sounds like you want to use any of a number of timer libraries that already exist.

Comment: I already updated the question.
I don't want real time updates in the comments exactly... I just want it to update the relative time like the facebook comments does.

Answer (score 0):

Computed cannot be used here, a computed property will never update, because `return moment(this.date).fromNow();` is not a reactive dependency.

In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens. I would then try to use a method instead of a computed property.